# The padx of the button is not intended?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

My project is a simple calculator:

I have a problem with the padx or the width of the button `button_subtract`;

the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

numEnter = Entry(root , width=58 ,borderwidth=5)
numEnter.grid(row=0 , column=0 , columnspan=4)


def button_click(num):
    current = numEnter.get()
    numEnter.delete(0 , END)
    numEnter.insert(0 , str(current) + str(num))


def button_add_func():
    first_num = numEnter.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = 'addition'
    f_num = int(first_num)
    numEnter.delete(0 , END)


def button_subtract_func():
    first_num = numEnter.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "subtraction"
    f_num = int(first_num)
    numEnter.delete(0 , END)


def button_multiply_func():
    first_num = numEnter.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = 'multiplication'
    f_num = int(first_num)
    numEnter.delete(0 , END)


def button_divide_func():
    first_num = numEnter.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = 'division'
    f_num = int(first_num)
    numEnter.delete(0 , END)


def button_equal_func():
    s_num = numEnter.get()
    numEnter.delete(0 , END)

    if math == 'addition':
        numEnter.insert(0 , int(s_num) + f_num)

    elif math == 'subtraction':
        numEnter.insert(0 , int(s_num) - f_num)

    elif math == 'multiplication':
        numEnter.insert(0 , int(s_num) * f_num)

    elif math == 'division':
        numEnter.insert(0 , int(s_num) / f_num)


def button_C():
    numEnter.delete(0 , END)


button_1 = Button(root , text="1" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root , text="2" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root , text="3" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root , text="4" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root , text="5" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root , text="6" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root , text="7" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root , text="8" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root , text="9" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root , text="0" , padx=40 , pady=20 , command=lambda: button_click(0))
button_add = Button(root , text="+" , padx=39 , pady=20 , command=button_add_func)
button_equal = Button(root , text="=" , padx=39 , pady=20 , command=button_equal_func)
button_clear = Button(root , text="Clear" , padx=20 , pady=148 , command=button_C)

button_subtract = Button(root , text='-' , padx=41 , pady=20 , command=button_subtract_func)
button_multiply = Button(root , text='×' , padx=39 , pady=20 , command=button_multiply_func)
button_divide = Button(root , text='÷' , padx=39 , pady=20 , command=button_divide_func)



button_9.grid(row=1 , column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1 , column=1)
button_7.grid(row=1 , column=2)

button_6.grid(row=2 , column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2 , column=1)
button_4.grid(row=2 , column=2)

button_1.grid(row=3 , column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3 , column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3 , column=2)

button_add.grid(row=4 , column=1)
button_equal.grid(row=5 , column=0)
button_clear.grid(row=1 , column=3, rowspan=5)

button_0.grid(row=4 , column=0)

button_subtract.grid(row=4 , column=2)
button_multiply.grid(row=5 , column=1)
button_divide.grid(row=5 , column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

but the result was:
[click me to see the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYr2v.png)

the button of subtract is not modified or i mean not intended in it right place!!

please a quick answer

Comment: Guys I tried to add 1 and subtract one from the padx attribute of the button `button_subtract` but it either get lesser than what the result i want or greater than the ressult i want :

i want the result to be modified correctly

Comment: It is better to use, for example, `width=15` instead of `padx=...`.  Same for using `height` instead of `pady`.

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer to my problem which is adding a space beside the `'-'` mark, the button code will be:

```
button_subtract = Button(root , text="- " , padx=39 , pady=20 , command=button_subtract_func)
```